# Making a filter for a text search that pulls info from a database and should ONLY show results if result fits filter

Tags: php, sql, forms, filter

I am trying to create a filter for a search plug-in on a website for a business I work for. The idea of the search bar is to allow people to find a record by way of the artist name OR the name of the album. The results are pulled from an online database. Currently, the code looks like this:

```
    <?php
$whereby = "";
if(count($_POST)>0){
    $albumsearch=$_POST['albumsearch'];
      echo "\n\nSearching For albums with name matching with \"${albumsearch}\"\n";
      echo '     <a class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color:#E91C2D; color:white; border-color:transparent" href="?page_id='. $page_id .'" role="button">Exit search</a>  </br> </br> </br>';
      $whereby = " WHERE title like '%".$albumsearch."%' OR artist like '%".$albumsearch."%' ";
      $query = ("SELECT TOP (10) * FROM (databaseName) $whereby");
    }
  else {
      $whereby =    "WHERE Image_URL_Link IS NOT NULL";
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM (databaseName) $whereby ORDER BY Release_Date DESC, Title ASC OFFSET $offst ROWS  FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY");
  }  

 //New

$stmt = sqlsrv_query ($conn,$query);
print_r( sqlsrv_errors());
 
$count = 0;
  while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) { 
    ?>
```

I can't find a way to attach a filter that searches for the label column WHILE also searching for the artist or album name. I've tried the following two solutions but they haven't quite worked:

```
if($_POST['albumsearch'] && ($_POST['labelsearch'] === "All")){
    $albumsearch = $_POST['albumsearch'];
    $labelsearch = $_POST['labelsearch'];
    echo "\n\nSearching for albums with name matching \"${albumsearch}\"\n\n";
    echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color:#E91C2D; color:white; border-color:transparent" href="?page_id='. $page_id .'" role="button">Exit search</a>  </br> </br> </br>';
        $whereby = " WHERE title like '%".$albumsearch."%' OR artist like '%".$albumsearch."%' ";
        $query = ("SELECT TOP (10) * FROM (databaseName) $whereby");
} elseif ($_POST['albumsearch'] && $_POST['labelsearch']){
    echo "\n\nSearch for albums with name matching with \"$albumsearch\" under \"$labelsearch's\" catalogue\n\n";
    echo ' <a class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color:#E91C2D; color:white; border-color:transparent" href="?page_id='. $page_id .'" role="button">Exit search</a>  </br> </br> </br>';
        $whereby = " WHERE title LIKE '%".$albumsearch."%' OR artist LIKE '%".$albumsearch."%' HAVING label '%".$labelsearch."%' ";
        $query = ("SELECT TOP (10) * FROM (databaseName) $whereby");
} else{
    $whereby =  "WHERE Image_URL_Link IS NOT NULL";
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM (databaseName) $whereby ORDER BY Release_Date DESC, Title ASC OFFSET $offst ROWS  FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY");
```

AND

```
$whereby = "";
$albumsearch = $_POST['albumsearch'];
$labelsearch = $_POST['labelsearch'];
switch((count($_POST)>0)){
    case ($_POST['albumsearch']):
        echo "\n\nSearching for albums with name matching \"${albumsearch}\"";
        echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color:#E91C2D; color:white; border-color:transparent" href="?page_id='. $page_id .'" role="button">Exit search</a>  </br> </br> </br>';
        $whereby = " WHERE title like '%".$albumsearch."%' OR artist like '%".$albumsearch."%' ";
        $query = ("SELECT TOP (10) * FROM (databaseName) $whereby");
        break;
    case ($_POST['albumsearch'] && $_POST['labelsearch'] === "(label1)"):
        echo "\n\nSearch for albums with name matching with \"${albumsearch}\" under \"${labelsearch}'s\" catalogue";
        echo ' <a class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color:#E91C2D; color:white; border-color:transparent" href="?page_id='. $page_id .'" role="button">Exit search</a>  </br> </br> </br>';
            $whereby = " WHERE title LIKE '%".$albumsearch."%' OR artist LIKE '%".$albumsearch."%' HAVING label '(label)' ";
            $query = ("SELECT TOP (10) * FROM (databaseName) $whereby");
        break;
    case ($_POST['albumsearch'] && $_POST['labelsearch'] === "(label2)"):
        echo "\n\nSearch for albums with name matching with \"${albumsearch}\" under \"${labelsearch}'s\" catalogue";
        echo ' <a class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color:#E91C2D; color:white; border-color:transparent" href="?page_id='. $page_id .'" role="button">Exit search</a>  </br> </br> </br>';
            $whereby = " WHERE title LIKE '%".$albumsearch."%' OR artist LIKE '%".$albumsearch."%' HAVING label LIKE '(label2) ";
            $query = ("SELECT TOP (10) * FROM (databaseName) $whereby");
        break;
    default:
        $whereby =  "WHERE Image_URL_Link IS NOT NULL";
        $query = ("SELECT * FROM (databaseName) $whereby ORDER BY Release_Date DESC, Title ASC OFFSET $offst ROWS  FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY");
    break;
}
    }
```

Currently I've tried both radio buttons and a dropdown menu and I haven't been able to make either work. Anyone got any suggestions? (Database name is in parenthesis to keep the name of the company I work for private)

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination `AND` and `OR` like this with brackets.

`WHERE (title LIKE '%".$albumsearch."%' OR artist LIKE '%".$albumsearch."%') AND label like '%".$labelsearch."%'`